# Is there a pattern for LOOP-like macro mini-languages?

Tags: syntax-error, lisp, common-lisp, lisp-macros

I am attempting to answer the following exercise.

> Write a macro function OUR-IF that translates the following macro calls.
>
> ```
> (our-if a then b) translates to (cond (a b))
> (our-if a then b else c) translates to (cond (a b) (t c))
> ```

My solution is the following:

```
(defmacro our-if (test then then-clause &optional else else-clause)
  (if (equal 'else else)
    `(cond (,test ,then-clause) (t ,else-clause))
    `(cond (,test ,then-clause))))
```

That works fine, but I'm not totally satisfied by it. There's no syntax checking on the "then" and "else" arguments. Then could be anything. And if I gave the wrong symbol for "else", I'd get the wrong behaviour. The symbols aren't even checked to be symbols.

I could model them as keyword arguments and get close, but that's not exactly right either. It reminds me of the LOOP macro, which is a much more complicated example of the same thing. That made me wonder: how does LOOP do it? Maybe there's some pattern for "mini languages in macro arguments". But I couldn't find anything.

I found [the hyperspec page for LOOP](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm) which confirms that the grammar is complicated. But I don't know if there's a nice way to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what pattern matching is for.  There are a bunch of CL pattern matchers, [dsm](https://tfeb.github.io/dsm/) is one I am familar with which was designed for dealing with macros, albeit not quite this sort of 'let's just splice in some fortran' macro.

Using dsm in `defmacro`:

```
(defmacro our-if (&body forms)
  (destructuring-match forms
    ((test then value)
     (:when (eq then 'then))
     `(if ,test ,value))
    ((test then value else otherwise)
     (:when (and (eq then 'then)
                 (eq else 'else)))
     `(if ,test ,value ,otherwise))
    (otherwise
     (error "what?"))))
```

Or if you use the `define-matching-macro` form it includes as an example:

```
(define-matching-macro our-if
  ((_ test then value)
   (:when (eq then 'then))
   `(if ,test ,value))
  ((_ test then value else otherwise)
   (:when (and (eq then 'then)
               (eq else 'else)))
   `(if ,test ,value ,otherwise))
  (otherwise
   (error "what?")))
```

It may be that other matchers are better for the case where there are lots of literals, as here.

In the case of `loop` the syntax keywords are compared by name, not symbol equality.  Although it is definitely overkill in this simple case, you can do this pretty easily using [spam](https://tfeb.github.io/tfeb-lisp-hax/#simple-pattern-matching-spam):

```
(defun syntax-keyword (k)
  ;; return a predicate which matches a syntax keyword
  (let ((uk (string-upcase k)))
    (lambda (s)
      (and (symbolp s)
           (string= (symbol-name s) uk)))))

(defmacro our-if (&body forms)
  (destructuring-match forms
    ((&whole form test _ value)
     (:when (matchp form (list-matches (any) (syntax-keyword "then") (any))))
     `(if ,test ,value))
    ((&whole form test _ value _ otherwise)
     (:when (matchp form (list-matches (any) (syntax-keyword "then") (any)
                                       (syntax-keyword "else") (any))))
     `(if ,test ,value ,otherwise))
    (otherwise
     (error "what?"))))
```

This is pretty seriously over-the-top for this simple case, but for more general things it can help.

Answer (score 1):

The LOOP macro accepts symbols that are compared by *name* and not by identity to the keywords defined in the grammar (see [6.1.1.2 Loop Keywords](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/06_aab.htm)
). The section doesn't specify how the comparison by name is done, but in ECL and SBCL (I tried only two implementations), the expected case is upper-case (using `|for|` doesn't work). All three invocations below are equivalent:

```
(loop :for x :in list)

(loop for x in list)

(loop my-package::for x their-package::in list)
```

For your simple macro it can be sufficient to add checks as follows:

```
(defmacro our-if (test then then-clause 
                  &optional (else nil elsep) (else-clause nil ecp))
  (unless (string= then "THEN")
    (error "Keyword THEN expected, not ~s" then))
  (when elsep
    (unless (string= else "ELSE")
      (error "Keyword ELSE expected, not ~s" else))
    (unless ecp
      (error "ELSE keyword without an else clause")))
  (if elsep
    `(cond (,test ,then-clause) (t ,else-clause))
    `(cond (,test ,then-clause))))
```

Note the use of a `elsep` and `ecp` (if you prefer longer names: `else-clause-p`) in the lambda list to know if the optional arguments are given or not (depending on their default value would not be enough to disambiguate the different cases).

Answer (score 1):

One can also signal specific errors. Such a syntax error is in Common Lisp a *program error*.

**Example:**

Let's define a general error condition, which can report errors with `FORMAT`.

```
(define-condition simple-program-error (simple-error program-error) ())
```

An example macro expecting 42 as the argument.

```
(defmacro a (a)
  (if (not (eql a 42))
      (error 'simple-program-error
             :format-control
              "Wrong syntax for macro A. Argument is not 42, but is ~a"
             :format-arguments (list a))
    `',a))
```

testing it:

```
CL-USER 132 > (a 41)

Error: Wrong syntax for macro A. Argument is not 42, but is 41
  1 (abort) Return to top loop level 0.

Type :b for backtrace or :c <option number> to proceed.
Type :bug-form "<subject>" for a bug report template or :? for other options.

CL-USER 133 : 1 > :c 1

CL-USER 134 > (a 42)
42
```